# Android Development CellID in LTE network

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile, cellid, lte

I try to implement a function into my Android Application that finds out the cell id of the cell I'm in in a LTE network.
I recently read a lot about using **TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo()** and then filter for **CellInfoLte**, but also that it's not implemented on every device.
So in my case calling telephonymaganger.getAllCellInfo() returns **null**.

I'm testing with a Samsung phone, what seems not to be the best case.
Is there any way to find out the Cell ID or is it just not accessible yet?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem a few months ago when using getNeigbouringCells() and finally I found this:

> The cellid implementation varies from mobile device to mobile device
>   since these features are considered to be optional. for example:
>   Samsung (all devices): getNeigbouringCells () is not supported at all
>   and always returns an empty list.

Please take a look at this for more information:
http://wiki.opencellid.org/wiki/Android_library

You can check it with another phone but not Samsung phones. You can find so many reports about other vendors that have the same problem.